# Parameterizing sampling spaces

Tags: distributions, sampling

Say we have an **online** feed of data where every point has a set of **categorical** features $X_1, ... X_n$.

We don't know how often we see each feature in the feed (e.g. p($X_i)$ over time) but we want to **parameterize** the **sampling** of this feed around the features.

One naive **parameterization** specifies the **actual** **proportion** with which we sample tuples. But this parameterization quickly runs into problems.

E.g consider the following sampling **specification**:

- **Rule 1**: 50% of all incoming data points where $X_1= K_1$
- **Rule 2**: 100% of all incoming data points where $X_2= K_2$

Obviously some of these rules may be incompatible with each other! For example, if we always have $X_1=K_1$ and $X_2=K_2$ in the **input** stream, we would not be able to apply both Rule 1 and Rule 2  above. We can only apply one. This parameterization isn't thus helpful.

Without knowing the input distribution, how can we go about parameterizing the space of sampling rules?

---

#### Naive approach

A approach could work as follows. We use parameters $K_1,\ldots K_M$ (one $K$ for each available nominal in $X_1, \ldots X_N$) with $K_i \in \left[0,1\right]$.

Then, for a given data point, its probability of being accepted for the sample will be $\prod \text{Ber}\;(K_i)$ of the $K_i$ that apply.

The problem I see with the above is that:

1. As the number of nominals in the sampling rules increase, the parameter space "collapses" when many nominals are present in a given data point. That is, the $K's$ have to be very close to 1 for a given point with the nominals to be selected (product of quantities < 1 quickly reaches 0).

   This "collapsing" effect can be a problem if we need to learn what $K's$ to use (without priors) against some objective  (e.g. high sampling rates are concentrated in a small region).
2. The $K_i$'s don't have much of a meaning in terms of final sampling rates.

Are there any known distributions that can be used to govern this type of sampling, when not knowing anything/much about the underlying distribution of nominals in the input stream?

Comment: It seems you have no control over the data that enters the feed, so your proposed schemes are all rejection sampling. Why do any rejection at all? What is the **goal** of the sampling?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Let's say there is some cumulative reward that you get (delayed, over time) based on what data points we choose to sample (i.e. pick from the feed). The goal is to parameterize this selection/sampling so that we can learn on it.

Comment: Is there some real application you are thinking of? Or is this just a thought experiment? (I am having trouble understanding your precise setup, so if there is a definite problem, you might present that more directly.)

Comment: The goal is to ingest the "best" data, for some notion of quality. This is just a thought experiment.